# JavaScript : failed to change HTML cell colour dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, perl

The value "-50.9" and "10.87" has been assigned to the below html code as a variable (value1=-50.9; value2=10.87).

I got range of : (infinite -value to -35) , (-34 to -25) , (-24 to larger number)

I supposed that if the 'if condition' is true, the cell background-color should change?

```
<html>
<head>
<!--<script type="text/javascript">-->
<script language="JavaScript">
    function try() {                                                                                                                                                                                          
    if (-50.9 <= -25|| 10.87 <= -25) {                                                                                                                                                                                 
        document.getElementById("texas").style.backgroundColor='white';                                                                                                                                       
    } else if (-50.9 <= -35 || 10.87 <= -35) {                                                                                                                                                                         
        document.getElementById("texas").style.backgroundColor='blue';                                                                                                                                       
    } else {                                                                                                                                                                                           
        document.getElementById("texas").style.backgroundColor='pink';                                                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                  
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
</script>       
</head>
<body>
 <div id = "div1">
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td id = "texas"><a href="">A = 10.87<br>B = -50.9</a></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this able to work? Or the value should be a variable?

**EDIT**
I used a perl script to generate this html by printing the contents.
And the value1 and value2 are declared in the beginning of the script.
So when the script print the html table, it turns the variable into the value.
 Also why it's -50.9 and 10.87 in the JavaScript.

I was wondering is it possible to change the cell color whenever the if-else condition is true.
Let's say, in this case, the table cell color should be blue?
because for now, the table cell colour remains the same, nothing changes.

Comment: What's the actual question? What are you expecting, and what's happening?

Comment: as @D.Peter said - you're not actually calling the function - you're just declaring it

Comment: moreover, try is a keyword in javascript, change the name of you function

Comment: And don't use try as function name. [It's already used by javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: And white background may actually look like no change if your browser has white as default background colour.

Comment: Hi @Utkanos, thanks. I've just edited my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.Change Your HTML tr Tag and Assign Individual Id's For Value1 and Value 2**

```
   <tr>
   <td id = "texas"><a href="">
   A = <p id = "value1">10.87</p>
   <br>
   B = <p id = "value2">-50.9</p>
   </a>
   </td>
```

**2.Then Customize Your Javascript To Achieve your Result**

```
  function test() {

var value1 = document.getElementById("value1").innerText;

var value2 = document.getElementById("value2").innerText;

value1 = Number(value1);
value2 = Number(value2);

if (value1 <= -25 || value2 <= -25) {
    document.getElementById("texas").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
} else if (value1 <= -35 || value2 <= -35) {
    document.getElementById("texas").style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
} else {
    document.getElementById("texas").style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}
};
```

**3.Don't Forgot To Call The Function**

```
test();
```

Comment: I suggest you edit your answer and explain what was wrong in the original code and what changes you've made to address it.

Comment: Hi Subi , thanks for your answer, however, I still unable to get what i want. Apologize for not being clear in my question. I've just edited. Please have a look.

Comment: @Santa sry,  i hav some work now,  but i 'll update my answer within 4 hours,  trust me,  go and have a cup of coffee,  relax and enjoy...  After 4 hours ur answer is there ok